# css banner that stretches from left to right

Tags: css

Typically with my web-pages I'll have a `#wrapper` DIV that wraps the entire page and set to something like:

```css
#wrap {position: relative; width: 1000px; display: block; margin: auto;}
```

My question is, if, inside that I have a banner like so:

```css
#banner {width: 100%; display: block; height: 100px; background :#CCC;}
```

I then want that banner to go *outside* the margins of #wrapper and reach the sides of the window, no matter how big the window is.

How can I achieve this?

Here is a JS fiddle of what I can piece together: http://jsfiddle.net/MCms6/

Comment: or, make a better HTML structure!

Comment: but then that wouldnt move with the height of the banner, what if my content before #banner is different on each page?

Comment: @Chud37 Don't put something that that you want bigger than the container, in the container. Put it outside!

Comment: @thatidiotguy alright but then I still have the problem of positioning and placement to match the content inside #wrap.  These are not answers people!

Comment: What do you mean, they are all answers. You just need to do a little leg work. I mean we are giving you our time with suggestions and you whine. Why don't you go make an attempt at one.

Comment: To the extent that these comments are not answers, note that they were not *posted* as answers, either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve all your issues:

1. Make a container element for your `#banner`, so it can follow the flow of your document. Also position it relative to make it the parent to your banner.
2. Position `#banner` absolutely and you can stretch it as wide as you want.

---

**UPDATE** -  [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MCms6/2/)

***HTML***

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <h1>my content my content my content my content my content my content my content my content </h1>

    <div id="bannerHolder">
        <div class="banner">
            my Banner
        </div>
    </div>

     <h1>more content more content more content more content more content more content more content</h1>
</div>
```

***CSS***

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 140px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    background: #ccc;        
}

#bannerHolder {
    background: #aaa;
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
}

#bannerHolder .banner {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    position: absolute;
    background: #555;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100px;   
}
```

Comment: This is as best as I can see where your going with this and It doesnt seem to make sense to me: http://jsfiddle.net/MCms6/